# Why does stencil in texture paint not work?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I want to draw the pepsi logo on my modelled bottle can and i saw in a tutorial it can be done with stencil in texture mapping settings but when i click and drag over the object nothing happens.

here the tut: https://youtube.com/shorts/Bwzqhq4EABw?feature=share

file: [image]

Comment: please pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: file is now in question

Answer (score 1):

Recalculate the normals in *Edit* mode: Select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: ok i will try, thanks

Comment: tysm @moonboots it worked!